# Incorrect rotation of image - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, image-rotation

How can I plot the rotated crop images in separated figure and what is the problem that I do not get the rotation correct (e.g, k= 3 or 6)?

code:

```
clear;
clc;

RGB = imread('pillsetc.png');
I = rgb2gray(RGB);
bw = imbinarize(I);
bw = bwareaopen(bw,30);
bw = imfill(bw,'holes');

imshow(bw)

[B,L] = bwboundaries(bw,'noholes');

imshow(bw)

[labeledImage, numBlobs] = bwlabel(bw);


for k = 1 : numBlobs
  thisObject = ismember(labeledImage, k);
  measurements = regionprops(thisObject, 'Orientation', 'BoundingBox');
  croppedImage = imcrop(RGB, measurements.BoundingBox);
  angle = measurements.Orientation
  uprightImage = imrotate(croppedImage, angle);
  imshow(uprightImage);
  hold on
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that as you get the angle of the object, if you want to have them horizontal you must do:

```
uprightImage = imrotate(croppedImage, -angle);
```

and not:

```
uprightImage = imrotate(croppedImage, angle);
```

If I run this code on Mario:

[image: Original Mario]

```
clear;
clc;

RGB = imread('Small-mario.png');
I = rgb2gray(RGB);
bw = imbinarize(I);
bw = bwareaopen(bw,30);
bw = imfill(bw,'holes');

figure;
imshow(bw)

[B,L] = bwboundaries(bw,'noholes');

figure;
imshow(bw)

[labeledImage, numBlobs] = bwlabel(bw);


for k = 1 : numBlobs
  thisObject = ismember(labeledImage, k);
  measurements = regionprops(thisObject, 'Orientation', 'BoundingBox');
  croppedImage = imcrop(RGB, measurements.BoundingBox);
  angle = measurements.Orientation;
  uprightImage = imrotate(croppedImage, -angle);
  figure;
  imshow(uprightImage);
end
```

After that, Mario's head is horizontal:

[image: Horizontal Mario]

Comment: And if you want them vertical just do `uprightImage = imrotate(croppedImage, 90-angle);` or `uprightImage = imrotate(croppedImage, -90-angle);` depending on if you want Mario's nose up or down.